# How to Change "USER has no blog entries" Text

Tags: string-overrides

When you click on a user's blogs link and there are none he message "USER has no blog entries." comes up. I want to change that. I have tried using string overrides within settings.php but it does not seem to work. I used !username for the user as it is a link but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to isolate first exactly where this text is coming from. From your description, it sounds like you're using the core blog module which has this line here:

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21blog%21blog.pages.inc/function/blog_page_user/7

```
else {
  drupal_set_message(t('!author has not created any blog entries.', array('!author' => theme('username', array('account' => $account)))));
}
```

So the correct string you want to use (and what your string override in settings.php will be looking for) is

```
!author has not created any blog entries.
```

Using the [string overrides module](https://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides) or your settings file, its easy then to change this text to whatever your like

[image]